# Android emulator faster and smoother then real device

Tags: performance, android-emulator, android-x86

August 2013:

I have Android NDK Open GLES 2.0 simple Match3 game built for atom CPU

GPU and HAXM is enabled in emulator.

I run it on laptop (iCore 5 8GB, ATI Radeon HD 1GB) and PC (Core 2 Duo 8GB ATI Radeon 512MB) in emulator

Game runs smooth on all devices but not in emulator.

My question is "Why I see lags on PC and laptop?"

I read many posts and they advice to enable HAXM, GPU and build for atom.

OpenGL games run smooth on these PCs.
WebGL sites run smooth.

I think emulator with HAXM must run atom code on Intel CPU faster then mobile runs ARM code.
Also I think Desktop GPU must emulate OpenGLES 2.0 faster then mobile GPU does that.

What chain course lags ?

That question was asked many times in different forms but there is persistent improvements in emulator.
I think emulator of today August 2013 must run (NDK+atom+GPU) code faster then any phone just because it is same native 1 to 1 codes that run on more powerful, more hotter CPU and GPU.

I am able to record video of OpenGL game on my desktop.
I wish to record game play of Android game as well. 
That is why I wish to run it smooth at 30-60 FPS.

Does http://www.android-x86.org/ in VirtualBox may offer smoother gameplay ?

Comment: What you think "must" be the case and what *is* the case, are unrelated.  If you read the technical discussions of why the emulator is slow that have been posted, you will see that many functions which operate in hardware on a real device are simulated on an emulator, rather than sufficiently translated to be run on the corresponding hardware of the hosting system.

Comment: Thanks. I see how many efforts are done by Intel to make Atom to be top development platform. I hope I just missing one thing. May be someone configured emulator that runs faster and smoother. and will share configuration of emulator or maybe I need more powerful PC and someone will share configuration of PC that is enough. Also someone may know what exactly makes emulator slow.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using genymotion, it is the fastest emulator out there on the market right now